# Sharepoint Alerts

Tags: alert

Thanks very much for your responses so far!

I'm trying to set up a single alert in a basic Sharepoint site that is set so that only "Existing Items are Modified" and "When a Task Becomes Complete" generate alerts.

Does anybody have any idea what field Sharepoint alerts need to see modified so that it recognises it as complete, as for me both Status & % complete don't seem to be doing the trick.

Cheers - Rob

Comment: @ Rob: you the man. I had same issue and setting task Value to "complteted" instead of "complete" resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How long did you leave it before seeing if an email was sent?

It should just keep it's eye on Status - normally it sends an email right away but your server might be configured to only send alert emails once every so often (every 5mins, 30mins, etc).

You can also set this setting in the Alerts page for that particular task list (send immediately, or at a set time), so make sure it's set on "Send immediately" for that particular Alert first.

Comment: Like I said I've tried both but to no avail.

It's been about 3hrs and I've had nothing back - even though I set it to immediate. Maybe Sharepoint hates me haha

Comment: Sharepoint only recognises a task as complete when the status is set to "Completed" not "Complete" which I had in my list